# How to convert base64 encoded string into a file input to be uploaded as an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to be able to take a base64 encoded string and mimic it as if it were a file that i selected it from the "browse" feature.  Here is a short example:

```
<input type="file" id="file" />


<script>
    //I want to be able to access it here
    $("#file").files;
</script>
```

I want to be able to access the files array and use it as a normal file.  I currently get the base64 encoded string like so:

```
// resize the canvas and draw the image data into it
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
preview.appendChild(canvas); // do the actual resized preview
var base64String =  canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File elements are only usable by the user, you would need to transfer the base64 string as normal form submission and then decode it on the server.